# flutter build ci for ios app using github action

Tags: ios, flutter, github, github-actions, cicd

I'm creating a CI/CD in my project repo using github action for my ios application, when i run it i get this error

```
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/runner/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
```

my script

```
name: iOS CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - live
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - live
      
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    
    env:
      GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        channel: 'stable'
        architecture: x64
    - run: echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON > ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --dart-define="ENVIRONMENT=PROD"
```

Comment: The error is about `/Users/runner/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist` file. In your workflow, you're writing `GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON` to `ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`. Looks like you need to fix the paths.